# How many row should lock when using SELECT .. FOR UPDATE LIMIT 1

Tags: mysql, locking, limit, select-for-update

I have a simple table with an index on the `count` column

```
| Counts   | CREATE TABLE `Counts` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `count` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `count_i` (`count`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |

INSERT INTO Counts (id, count) VALUES (1, 4);
INSERT INTO Counts (id, count) VALUES (2, 4);
INSERT INTO Counts (id, count) VALUES (3, 4);
INSERT INTO Counts (id, count) VALUES (4, 2);
INSERT INTO Counts (id, count) VALUES (5, 2);
```

I'm attempting this

```
SELECT * FROM Counts WHERE count >= 4 ORDER BY count LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE of Counts SKIP LOCKED`
```

The idea is to let MySQL skip the already locked row and give me back the next "non" locked row.

However with my testing it looks like all the rows with `count >= 4` are locked even though I use a `LIMIT 1`

From what I understand MySQL will not lock the 'returned' row only but all the row it has scanned to arrived at this result.

`EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM Counts WHERE count >= 4 ORDER BY count LIMIT 1`

```
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Counts | NULL       | range | count_i       | count_i | 4       | NULL |    3 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------+
```

So here is why the 3 rows are locked but I don't understand why.

However if instead of ordering by count I order by the PRIMARY KEY `id` I get 1

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM Counts WHERE count >= 4 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Counts | NULL       | index | count_i       | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL |    1 |    60.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
```

Isn't the fact that I have added an index on `count` and using `order by count` enough to have only one row scanned and thus locked ?

Is it my mysql docker that is acting strange ?

```
SELECT @@global.transaction_ISOLATION; == READ-COMMITTED

SELECT @@version == 8.0.33
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So here is why the 3 rows are locked but I don't understand why.
>
> However if instead of ordering by count I order by the PRIMARY KEY id
> I get 1

Using InnoDB Engine it locks every row it had to look at.

- UNIQUE index on the column (Primary Key is considered unique in MySQL)

  Only one row need , locked.
- A non-unique INDEX on the column
  It must lock all the rows with
  that value.
- No index on the column.
  If no index present it has to scan all table, so all rows are locked.

Comment: Hey! I know this is an old question but I'd like to ask something: i tested this query `select * from tbl t where tbl.status = 1 and tbl.another_column = 5 limit 1 for update skip locked;` and it locks just one row (the returned on the result set). it doesn't go against what you said? or I misinterpreted something..
Hundreds of thousands of rows match `tbl.status = 1 and tbl.another_column = 5` but only the returned on the result set was locked and I even doubl checked it by doing `select * from performance_schema.data_locks;`

Comment: Hey! It doesn't had any impact on my case. AFAIK, MySQL would have to lock only the row returned in the result set. Don't it? I expected it to be this way. Anyway, I entered this discussion because I'm having a problem when using LIMIT in conjunction with FOR UPDATE. I just asked a question regarding this subject, but it is on MySQL 5.7:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77448648/select-limit-for-update-behavior-in-mysql-5-7

Answer (score 2):

InnoDB locks all records it encounters while scanning the range, not just the ones that match the condition (even if you use LIMIT 1).
To avoid locking all rows, you can try use nested subquery.

```
SELECT * FROM Counts WHERE id = (
      SELECT id FROM Counts WHERE count >= 4 ORDER BY count LIMIT 1
    ) FOR UPDATE;
```

Keep in mind that this approach might have performance implications, as it involves two queries instead of one

Comment: When you use ORDER BY id, MySQL optimizer chooses to use the PRIMARY index instead of the count_i index. In this case, the range scan is not performed on the count_i index, so only one row is locked.

Answer (score 1):

@Alexis, You might want to check this - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/limit-optimization.html

Especially this:

> If you combine LIMIT row_count with ORDER BY, MySQL stops sorting as soon as it has found the first row_count rows of the sorted result, rather than sorting the entire result. If ordering is done by using an index, this is very fast. If a filesort must be done, all rows that match the query without the LIMIT clause are selected, and most or all of them are sorted, before the first row_count are found. After the initial rows have been found, MySQL does not sort any remainder of the result set.

Other points are also important...

Comment: So, in the case of 1st query, no index is used, so it scans through all the 3 records, even if it has to return just 1.  But, in the case of the 2nd query, where it uses index, it just stops after going through the first record - so locks only 1.