# Select * for update too slow

Tags: sql, mysql, spring-data-jpa, innodb

I have this code as a distributed lock implementation in a Spring app using Mysql as DB.

```
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY, isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
    public void obtainLock(String lockKey) {
        entityManager.flush(); // Flush any pending INSERTs/UPDATEs to the DB before taking the lock
        Optional<Lock> lock = lockRepository.getLock(lockKey);
        if (lock.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                lockRepository.createLock(lockKey);
                entityManager.flush(); // Make sure the INSERT is issued to the DB immediately
                lockRepository.getLock(lockKey);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000L);
                    lockRepository.getLock(lockKey);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    if (e instanceof InterruptedException) {
                        // Restore interrupted state...
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
    }
```

lockKey column is primary Id.

```
public interface LockRepository extends Repository<Lock, String> {
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "insert ignore into Locks (lockKey) values (:key)", nativeQuery = true)
    void createLock(@Param("key") String key);

    @org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    @Query("select l from Lock l where l.lockKey = :key")
    Optional<Lock> getLock(@Param("key") String key);
}
```

Through monitoring mysql slow query logs I found the **lockRepository.getLock(lockKey)** method could take 5s on average and some could take tens of seconds. This is the sql query statement by that query method:

```
select  lock0_.lockKey as lockKey1_294_
    from  Locks lock0_
    where  lock0_.lockKey={value}
    for update  /*** source: LockRepository.getLock ***/;
```

What I know is that the select * for update is a form of pessimistic lock, and since lockKey is primaryId/indexed, it will lock the record, not the whole table.

What could be the cause for the performance slowness?

----------------edit---------------
[image]

Comment: It will lock as many rows it had to look at . You haven't post any execution plan . See my answer on [How many row should lock when using SELECT .. FOR UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76098834/how-many-row-should-lock-when-using-select-for-update-limit-1#76099276) for a detailed explanation on rows locking

Comment: Please post TEXT results of  EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE (rest of your query); so we can see where you are likely missing indexes.

Comment: Let's see the `BEGIN...COMMIT` -- that is the entire transaction.  Also what are other threads doing at the same time?  And `SHOW CREATE TABLE Locks`

Comment: I've updated my original post with execution plan. Any idea?