# SELECT ... LIMIT ... FOR UPDATE behavior in MySQL 5.7

Tags: sql, mysql

**MySQL 5.7** using InnoDB.

Simple test schema:

```sql
create table test(
    id int primary key,
    name varchar(8)
);
```

Insert 50 rows:

```sql
insert into test values (1, 'Test 1'), (2, 'Test 2') .... till 50 rows
```

I want to `SELECT ... LIMIT OFST, LMT ... FOR UPDATE` so I can lock `LMT` rows.

**Test 1:**

**Transaction 1:**

```sql
begin 
    select * from test limit 0, 1 for update; (1)
    sleep(10); -- locking for 10 seconds for sake of testing
commit
```

Returned rows from (1):

```
id|name  |
--+------+
 1|Test 1|
```

**Transaction 2:**

```sql
begin 
    select * from teste where id = 2 for update; (1)
commit
```

Transaction 2 returns immediately, without having to wait 10 seconds for Transaction 1 to commit. Ok, expected.

**Test 2:**

**Transaction 1:**

```sql
begin 
    select * from test limit 0, 1 for update;
    sleep(10);
commit;
```

Returned rows from (1):

```
id|name  |
--+------+
 1|Test 1|
```

**Transaction 2:**

```sql
begin 
    select * from test limit 1, 1 for update; (1)
commit;
```

Returned rows from (1):

```
id|name  |
--+------+
 2|Test 2|
```

Even tho Transaction 2 returned a different result set, it had to wait 10 seconds for Transaction 1 to commit. Why does that happen? Is there any workaround to it? If it were MySQL 8.0+, a simple `SKIP LOCKED` would resolve my scenario.

I'm working on a system need to select vouchers from a pool of codes that live in a table so it can sell them. This is a legacy system.

The system does the following query:

```
select
    *
from
    vouchers v
where
    v.status = 1
limit
    0, ? -- limit inferred by programming language (it can be 1 to 50)
for update
```

The problem is that, when there is a high throughput, the application starts to collapse because of all the transactions waiting for others to commit (due to the locks). How to avoid this?

Comment: Using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is asking for trouble. I suspect there's a gap lock involved.

Comment: @Barmar. . . please, could you explain a bit more on how could an order by help fix this issue?

Comment: I don't know if it will fix the problem. But the ordering is unpredictable without it, so there's no reason why the second query wouldn't  try to access the same row.

Comment: @Barmar. . . in the scenario I stated at the end of the question, would you suggest another way of obtaining vouchers?

Comment: I don't see how you can do this without waiting for the commit. You want to ensure that transaction 2 doesn't try to use the same voucher as transaction 1, right? It has to wait for t1 to commit the update to the `status` column to reserve that voucher.

Comment: @Barmar. . . Correct. I tested on a MySQL 8.0+ and the `SKIP LOCKED` worked like a charm. Sadly this feature is not available in 5.7. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: They presumably added that because there's no way to get the equivalent functionality without it.

Comment: In the absence of an order by and where clause that would use an index enableing mysql to narrow down the number of rows it needs to scan, your select statement likely locks the entire table, not just the retrieved row.

Comment: @Shadow. . . I don't think I'm locking the entire table. The Test 1 I made show this is not happening, doesn't it? I mean, I was able to `select * from test where id = 2 for update` without having to wait for the lock to be released on the first transaction. Doesn't this prove the table wasn't entirely locked? Maybe I'm missing something or I misinterpreted you.

Comment: In the first test your 2nd transaction uses the PK to work out the row it needs. In your 2nd test, the 2nd transaction needs to examine the whole table and gets stuck.

Comment: @Shadow. . . understood! then a `select ... for update` on a specific row (eg. using a pk) might not be blocked by a table-level lock? Is that it?

Comment: It's not a table level lock per se. If a locking statement cannot use a unique index, then it will lock all index records it encounters while scanning the table or the inon-unique index. If two statements in different transactions use the same index for locking, then the firat blocks oit the second one. Hiwever, if the second statement uses a different unique index to narrow down the rows being locked, then the locks placed by the first transaction do not block it out.

Comment: @Shadow. . . I tested what you said on MySQL 8.0. Why does `select * from test limit 0, 1 for update;` not block all rows? I tested with `skip locked`. . . transaction 1 `select * from test limit 0, 1 for update;` locks and returns test1 . . . | . . .  transaction 2 `select * from test limit 0, 1 for update skip locked;` is not blocked and immediately locks and returns test2. . . If the whole table was locked wouldn't transaction 2 return an empty result set? Regarding this subject, does 8.0+ behaves different than 5.7?

Comment: MySQL 5.7 reached end of life 8 days ago, and there will be no more security patches. You should consider upgrading asap.

Comment: @TheImpaler. . . yes, I know it. But sadly the upgrade is not my decision. It is a new project I'm working on. I just arrived here. Thanks for the advice tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL manual on [innodb locks set by sql statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locks-set.html) has the key points that describe the behaviour you experience.

1. Row level locks are in fact index record locks.
2. Locking reads lock all rows they encounter while searching for the rows to retrieve, even if the row is later excluded from the resultset.
3. If there is a suitable unique index to determine exactly which row(s) need locking, only those rows get locked.
4. If there is no suitable index to use for a locking read, then the statement must scan the entire table, effectively locking all rows.

Based on the above rules, the 1st test's 1st transaction starts a table scan locking rows probably in their physical order. The limit part stops the locking after the first record.

This is why the 2nd transaction can return immediately, as it uses the PK to retrieve and thus lock the row with id=2.

However, the 2nd transaction of the 2nd test blocks as in the absence of an index, MySQL has to start reading the entire table from the first row as it cannot determine the second one without scanning the first. It tries to lock the first row, but has to wait until the 1st transaction commits.